# The Ruby %r{ } expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a model there is a field

```
validates :image_file_name, :format => { :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$}i
```

It looks pretty odd for me. I am aware that this is a regular expression. But I would like:

- to know what exactly it means. Is `%r{value}` equal to `/value/` ?
- be able to replace it with normal Ruby regex operator `/some regex/` or `=~`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

`%r{}` is equivalent to the `/.../` notation, but allows you to have '/' in your regexp without having to escape them:

```
%r{/home/user}
```

is equivalent to:

```
/\/home\/user/
```

This is only a syntax commodity, for legibility.

Edit:

Note that you can use almost any non-alphabetic character pair instead of '{}'.
These variants work just as well:

```
%r!/home/user!
%r'/home/user'
%r(/home/user)
```

Edit 2:

Note that the `%r{}x` variant ignores whitespace, making complex regexps more readable. Example from [GitHub's Ruby style guide](https://github.com/github/rubocop-github/blob/master/STYLEGUIDE.md#regular-expressions):

```rb
regexp = %r{
  start         # some text
  \s            # white space char
  (group)       # first group
  (?:alt1|alt2) # some alternation
  end
}x
```

Comment: The downvote was 1 hour ago only. As for space as delimiter, this is awesome, but not the sort of thing I will recommand to be able to read your code without beeing puzzled six month later :)

Comment: If you use spaces as your delimiter, your regular expression will break if you add spaces to it later. I think the idea is to use delimiters that don't match anything in your regular expression, with curly braces as the preferred default.

Comment: It's almost as if ruby was designed to write as horrible code as possible

Comment: Don't understand the note of your second edit. What is special about `%r{}x`? `/.../x` also ignores whitespace. This is no special property of `%r` syntax. All options that can follow `/../` can also follow `%r{}`.

Answer (score 13):

With `%r`, you could use any delimiters.

You could use `%r{}` or `%r[]` or `%r!!` etc.

The benefit of using other delimeters is that you don't need to escape the `/` used in normal regex literal.

Answer (score 10):

`\.` => contains a dot
`(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)` => then, either one of these extensions
`$` => the end, nothing after it
`i` => case insensitive

And it's the same as writing `/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i`.

Comment: Is %r{value} equal to /value/ ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. - As `%w[1 2 3]` is the same as `[1, 2, 3]` for example.

Comment: `%w[1 2 3]` is *not* the same as `[1, 2, 3]`. It is the same as `['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the rectification.

Answer (score 3):

this regexp matches all strings that ends with .gif, .jpg...

you could replace it with

```
/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

It mean that `image_file_name` must end (`$`) with dot and one of gif, jpg, jpeg or png.

Yes `%r{}` mean exactly the same as `//` but in `%r{}` you don't need to escape `/`.