# Check whether a string contains / (forward slash) or \ (backward slash) using regex

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I find the string, that contains / (forward slash) or \ (backward slash) or both using Regexp?

Ex. I have following array `['ABC', 'abc/sd', dsa\adf', as/\sfd', ball, cat]`

then it will return only those strings that contain slash.

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape them in the regex. Try

```
a = ['ABC', 'abc/sd', 'dsa\adf', 'as/\sfd', 'ball', 'cat']
a.select { |s| s.match(/[\/\\]/) }
 => ["abc/sd", "dsa\\adf", "as/\\sfd"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by using [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) with regex argument:

```
arr = ['ABC', 'abc/sd', 'dsa\adf', 'as/\sfd', 'ball', 'cat']
regex = %r{[\\/]}
arr.grep(regex)
=> ["abc/sd", "dsa\\adf", "as/\\sfd"]
```

- using `%r()` notation lets you [omit escaping slash `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384762/2933305),
- using `Enumerable#grep` is a bit more compact that `Enuberable#select` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Im not a ruby programmer, but u shouldnt use regex for such simple tasks this overkill as regexps are resource hungry. Every language offers a function to find a string within another. Sometimes its called instr, instring or whatever ... What u are looking for is

rindex(substring [, fixnum])

Returns the index of the last occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str.

"hello".rindex('a')             #=> nil

If u get nil the string "a" in ur case slash is not found.

Comment: That is not true. Ruby `Enumerable#grep` is optimized for this operation. It matches, without assigning the matched results to any variables. Inspect `$~` variable after performin `Enumerable#gsub`, its empty.