# Replace all words before the start of the first word (Regex and Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex

Here are my test cases.

Expected:

`JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech` should be `http://francium.tech`
`JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech/http` should be `http://francium.tech/http`
`francium.tech/http` should be `francium.tech/http` (unaffected)

Actual result:

```
http://francium.tech
francium.tech/http
http
```

I am trying to write a regex replace for this. I tried this,

```
text.sub(/.*http/,'http')
```

However, my second and third test cases fail because it searches till the end. It would help if the answer could also do the case insensitivity.

```
2.5.0 :001 > url = 'francium.tech/http'
 => "francium.tech/http" 
2.5.0 :002 > url.sub(/^.*?(?=http)/i,'')
 => "http"
```

Comment: As I said with your original question: [`^.*?(?=http://)`](https://regex101.com/r/90CfPK/2/)

Comment: @ctwheels - the third case fails

Comment: No it doesn't :)

Comment: .*?(?=http:\/\/), you need escape char /

Comment: @ShenYudong you don't need to escape the `/` if you use [`%r{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384704/the-ruby-r-expression)

Comment: @bragboy you're not using my entire pattern. Add the `://` and use `%r{}` as my previous comment suggests.

Comment: Based on the comments, is this not ok?: [http://rextester.com/NLAF10843](http://rextester.com/NLAF10843)

Comment: @ctwheels: I should not use that because it could be http or https

Comment: @bragboy then that's something you should specify in the question no? `^.*?(?=https?://)`

Comment: @bragboy you should know that you need to present us with all the information required to assist you. Without all that information your question can easily be seen as a duplicate of another (which was the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my original comments, you can use the pattern as shown below. If you want a *really small* performance gain, you can remove one step in the regex by using the second pattern instead. If you're especially concerned with performance, the last one performs even quicker.

```
^.*?(?=https?://)
^.*?(?=https?:/{2})
^.*?(?=ht{2}ps?:/{2})
```

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7ikKDMvvVjBViGai1PJK9TP29PPLcjfLySjpKTASl8/rSgxLzmzNFevJDU5Q0mHsBp9kCBYIRZhrlguqIV6qYnJGQrVCjXFNQoFpSXFCsV6xaVJGqpF1XF6WvYa9rYg9cX2QNM1a3UU1NU1FWr//wcA)

```
strings = [
    "JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech",
    "JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech/http",
    "francium.tech/http"
]
strings.each { |s| puts s.sub(%r{^.*?(?=https?://)}, '') }
```

Outputs the following:

```
http://francium.tech
http://francium.tech/http
francium.tech/http
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may solve your problem.

```
str1 = 'JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech'# should be http://francium.tech 
str2 = 'JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech/http'# should be http://francium.tech/http
str3 = 'francium.tech/http' #should be francium.tech/http (unaffected)
str4 = 'JUNKINFRONThttps://francium.tech/http'# should be https://francium.tech/http

[str1, str2, str3, str4].each do |str|
  puts str.gsub(/^.*(http|https):\/\//i, "\\1://")
end

Result:
http://francium.tech
http://francium.tech/http
francium.tech/http
https://francium.tech/http
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `^.*?(?=https?://)` and you don't need the capture group

Answer (score 2):

When using regex you should make sure to use unique strings like `http:\\` or better `http:\\[SOMETHING].[AT_LEAST_TWO_CHARS][MAYBE_A_SLASH]` and so on...

This works for your given cases:

```
str = ['JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech',
    'JUNKINFRONThttp://francium.tech/http',
    'francium.tech/http']

str.each do |str|
    puts str.sub(/^.*?(https?:\/{2})/, '\1')  # with capturing group
    puts str.sub(/^.*?(?=https?:\/{2})/, '')  # with positive lookahead
end
```

By using a group we can use it for the replacement, another method would be to use a positive lookahead

Comment: the positive lookahead needs less memory, so that should be the way to go!
http://tpcg.io/6paRVE